# API endpoint not showing in swagger ui but is reachable

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, ruby-grape, napa

I have a grape swagger ui running in a docker compose project.  the app builds and is browseable.  the problem I have is I create a new API with the Napa generator (people in this case) and it does not show up in the swagger ui.  I can log into the container running the grape app and can curl the api and get a response.

code is at https://github.com/nungster/docker-napa-swagger
docker-compose up -d
browser to http://dockermachineIP:8080/api/index.html
and then you can explore it at http://dockermachineIP:8080/swagger_doc
the hello and swagger_doc endpoints show up, but what about my peopleApi?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the default hello api has just add_swagger_documentation declared and it appears in the Swagger UI, I had to modify what I did in my API.  I was missing a mount point.  I had assumed it would have worked the same as the hello API but I was wrong.

add_swagger_documentation api_version:'v0.1', mount_path: "/docs"